# Derivative of -I (Log[-x] - Log[x]) - why is it zero?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, complex, integral-transforms

Mathematica gives the derivative of the function `-I (Log[-x] - Log[x])` as $0$, but on the real domain the expected result is $\pi\delta(x)$ and on complex domain it is much more complicated. Mostly on the complex plane the function is smooth, differentiable and non-constant. Why do I get its derivative zero? How can I get the true expression for the derivative?

The function can be represented as

$$-i(\ln(-x)-\ln x)=2 \arg(-x)-\pi$$

This is the plot of the desired derivative:
[image]

It was obtained with the following command:

`ComplexPlot3D[-2 Derivative[1][Arg][-x], {x, -3 - 3 I, 3 + 3 I}, WorkingPrecision -> 100]`

It is zero only along the real axis.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk the derivative function cannot differentiate ```Sign[x]```. Additionally, it is undefined for complex values. The original function is well defined on the whole complex plane.

Comment: That derivative is zero because of the chain rule. Which means it vanishes on C, not just R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Mathematica* doesn't yield results using generalized functions unless Fourier/Laplace transforms are involved. So, differentiate using a transform.

```
LaplaceTransform[-I (Log[-x] - Log[x]), x, s]
(* -I ((EulerGamma + Log[s])/s - (EulerGamma - I \[Pi] + Log[s])/s) *)
InverseLaplaceTransform[s %, s, x]
(* \[Pi] DiracDelta[x] *)
```

Comment: Okay. But what about the complex case? Dirac Delta is not defined on complex arguments. But the original function is differentiable.

Comment: @Anixx That *is* the complex case.

Comment: @Anixx What makes you think DiracDelta is undefined for complex arguments?

Comment: Try evaluate it in Mathematica

Comment: The function in question is smooth everywhere except at zero, so its derivative should be continuous. $$-i(\ln(-x)-\ln x)=2 \arg(-x)-\pi$$

Comment: @Anixx Perhaps that behavior is a bug. You might want to look at this: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/118101/dirac-delta-function-with-a-complex-argument

Comment: Added the plot to the question.

Comment: It is zero only on real axis

Comment: `{-I (Log[-x] - Log[x]), 2 Arg[-x] - Pi} /. x -> I` yields `{-\[Pi], -2 \[Pi]}`

Comment: Okay, so the representation via arg is not perfect, but there is no other way to build the complex plot of derivative of this function.

Comment: @Anixx `-I (Log[-(x + I y)] - Log[ x + I y]) // ComplexExpand` yields `Arg[-x - I y] - Arg[x + I y]`, which is just ±π.

Comment: So, my question is flawed. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnDoty: `LaplaceTransform[-I (Log[-x] - Log[x]), x, s, 
 GenerateConditions -> True]` results in `ConditionalExpression[
 (-I)*((EulerGamma + Log[s])/
    s - (EulerGamma - I*Pi + 
     Log[s])/s), Re[s] > 0]`.

Comment: @JohnDoty:  `InverseLaplaceTransform` up to tits definition in the documentation `Integrate[
 Exp[x*(1 + 
      I*t)]*(-I)*((EulerGamma + Log[1 + I*t])/(1 + 
       I*t) - (EulerGamma - I*Pi + Log[1 + I*t])/(1 + 
       I*t)), {t, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals]` results in `-(1/2) I E^x \[Pi] ((1/Sqrt[\[Pi]])(MeijerG[{{1/2,1,1},{}},{{1},{}},(2 I)/Abs[x],1/2]+I MeijerG[{{1/2,1/2,1},{}},{{1/2},{}},(2 I)/Abs[x],1/2] Sign[x])+2 CosIntegral[I Abs[x]] (Cosh[Abs[x]]-Sign[x] Sinh[Abs[x]])+(Cosh[Abs[x]] Sign[x]-Sinh[Abs[x]]) (I \[Pi]+2 SinhIntegral[Abs[x]]))`.